# FAIL: bootable Ubuntu USB on Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: boot, usb, windows

The live USB works fine on desktops so I know it is fine. But I need it on my laptop. I have disabled secure boot, and enabled legacy booting. My BIOS doesn't have a quick boot option to disable. I get this message each time:

```
Warning: no configuration file found.
boot:
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like that laptop doesn't support USB booting.  I've had several computers that wouldn't take a USB drive to boot off of *directly*.  You had to set up a bootloader on an internal drive which pointed at the external drive.  You might try burning a DVD and using that, or possibly, if you're looking for a long term install, repartition the hard drive. There are tools to do that in Windows 8.

Comment: And if that's the case (can't boot USB directly) - http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html. I would use Parted Magic for repartitioning...

Comment: Ah!  Just saw your warning display.  Can you type something in at the "boot:"?  If so, give "boot linux" or "linux" a try.  Might be "ubuntu".

Comment: For clarification, this is a new UEFI system. No DVD drive. The BIOS boot menu allows USB selection, plus the advanced startup options includes a " use USB " option, so it seems unlikely the system doesn't support USB booting, right?

Comment: Ok if I type linux it says:" linux.c32 missing kernel name " if I type the othersuggrstions it says no such file or directory

Comment: bring up the usb drive on another machine and find the kernel and use that name after linux.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, the Rufus USB bootable disk tool. It specifically configures the drive for use with UEFI, which the tool linked on the Ubuntu site apparently does not. Here it is:

https://rufus.akeo.ie/

I can now load Ubuntu, Kali, and TAILS successfully with the drives I created using this tool.